# Beginning Java Polymorphism Subclass Superclass

Tags: java, class, object, subclass, superclass

I am trying to practice with Polymorphism and using classes.  I wrote a superclass called `Card`.  I then wrote 3 subclasses called: `IDCard`, `CallingCard`, and `DriverLicense`.  I then wrote another class called `Billfold` which is supposed to contain slots for two of the cards.
I am supposed to write a `BillfoldTester` program which adds two objects of different subclasses to a `Billfold` object.

In `BillfoldTester`, a `DriverLicense` object and a `CallingCard` object are instantiated and added to a `Billfold`, which refers to these objects with `Card` references.

I don't really understand how to do this.  I created two `Card` objects but I am trying to add it to my `Billfold` and it wont work.  I tried `Billfold a = new Card (x);` but it's not right... Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class BillfoldTester
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Card x= new IDCard("Julie", 1995);
        Card j= new DriverLicense("Jess", 1997);
  //Having trouble trying to put the objects into my Billfold and print it.
    }
}

public class Billfold extends Card
{
    private String card1;
    private String card2;

    void addCard(String Card)//Not sure if this should be String
    {
        card1=Card;
    }
}

public class Card
{

   private String name;

   public Card()
   //This is my superclass
   {
      name = "";
   }

   public Card(String n)
   {
      name = n;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public boolean isExpired()
   {
      return false;
   }

   public String format()
   {
      return "Card holder: " + name;
   }
}
  public class IDCard extends Card
{
    //This is one of my subclasses
    private int IDNumber;
    public IDCard (String n, int id)

    {
        super(n);
        this.IDNumber=id;
    }
    public String format()
    {
        return super.format() + IDNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory, when class B extends class A this means that B is some more special kind of A and that B can behave as an A. An `IDCard` is a special `Card` and can do everything a `Card` can. But can you say that about a billfold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polymorphism example. Not sure if the functionally is exactly what you need, but you can see the whole idea (I hope). See the showAllFormat() method of Billfold class.

The whole point is inside different format() methods of the DriverLicense and IDCard. Depending on the 'real' (or initially assigned) object the different method will be called even if you just only refer to 'Card' class.

NOTE:
You didn't provide your DriverLicense implementation, and my is just from head. I have a bit different constructor to show this sub-classes may be totally different.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class Billfold {
    List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>(10);

    void addCard(Card card) // Q: Not sure if this should be String
                            // A: You would like to add a Card
    {
        list.add(card);
    }

    void showAllFormat() {
        // go polymorphism !...
        // when you call this general 'format()' you see the subclasses
        // 'format()' is executed, not from 'Card' class
        for(Card x: list) {
            System.out.println(x.format());            
        }
    }
}

class Card {
    private String name; /* owner */

    public Card() //This is my superclass
    {
        name = "";
    }

    public Card(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    public String format() {
        return "Card holder: " + name;
    }
}

class IDCard extends Card {
    //This is one of my subclasses
    private int IDNumber;

    public IDCard(String n, int id) {
        super(n);
        this.IDNumber = id;
    }

    public String format() {
        return "(ID)" + super.format() + " " + IDNumber;
    }
}

class DriverLicense extends Card {
    private String type;

    public DriverLicense(String n, String type) {
        super(n);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String format() {
        return "(DL)" + super.format() + " TYPE: " + type;
    }
}

public class BillfoldTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card x = new IDCard("Julie", 1995);
        Card j = new DriverLicense("Jess", "AB");

        Billfold bf = new Billfold();
        bf.addCard(x);
        bf.addCard(j);

        bf.showAllFormat();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing and explaining the concept to me. this really helped thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.  A Billfold is not a Card; it HAS Cards.

```
public class Billfold
{
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    void addCard(Card card) {
        if (card != null) {
            this.cards.add(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're largely on the right track, just a couple of things:

```
void addCard(String Card)//Not sure if this should be String
{
    card1=Card;
}
```

You're right, this should be:

```
void addCard(Card card)
{
    card1=card;
}
```

then to add them:

```
public class BillfoldTester
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Card x= new IDCard("Julie", 1995);
        Card j= new DriverLicense("Jess", 1997);
        Billfold bf = new Billfold();
        Billfold.addCard(x);
        Billfold.addCard(j);
    }
}
```

Then add a method to `Billfold` to print the cards in it.

Edit: Oh yeah, and duffymo is totally right, you don't need to `extends Card` on `Billfold`

Comment: Wouldn't I need Billfold extends Card because my IDCard subclass has a format method that Billfold can use to print the cards?  Sorry, I am confused....  this wouldnt work                     public String formatCards()
{
return card1.format();
}

Comment: @LindsayBaird You need to have to `String formatCards` method on the `Card` class - then you can override it in a subclass. Take a look at flyer's answer for how to go about doing that. That way when you have a `Card` object you know that it has a `formatCards` method - otherwise you'd have to know you were holding an `IDCard`.

Comment: I have the format method in my super and subclass...Do I have to put the objects into an ArrayList to print them?  I am trying to call it in my Billfold like I did in my IDCard class but its not letting me do it....

Comment: You need to have a method in `BillFold` like `public void Print(){x.formatCards(); j.formatCards();}`. That ought to do it, without `BillFold` extending `Card`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Billfold` class have two `Card` objects, not two `Strings`:

```
public class Billfold
{
    Card card1;
    Card card2;

    void addCard(Card card) {
        if (card != null) {
            if (card1 != null) {
                this.card1 = card;
            } else {
                this.card2 = card;
            }
    }

}
```